# Unrar error code: 10

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I have installed `unrar-nonfree` from source on the raspberry pi 2 for OSMC based on Debian Jessie but most nzb's don't unpack. I get `Unrar error code: 10`

Comment: First try it with `sudo` and then have a look through [here](http://nzbget.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=786).

Answer (score 2):

Absolute paths are required in NZBGet's settings like so: `/usr/bin/unrar` `/usr/bin/7z`. it's relative paths by default.